# Nested include for Tikz daigram of separate competent

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to separate a document into components then only include whole components, however one of the components contains an include tag for a tikz diagram and I am receiving: `LaTeX Error: \include cannot be nested.`

Is there any way that I can simply include the Tikz figure within that component, that will allow it to be included in the main document as is?

This is the set up:

**a.tex** (diagram)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**component.tex**

```
\begin{center}
    \include{diagrams/a}
\end{center}
```

**main.tex**

```
\section{"component"}
\include{components/component}
```

Comment: Use `\input` rather than `\include`. `\include` is intended for e.g. complete chapters and cannot be nested. `\input` can be nested and can be used in `\include`d files.

Comment: @cfr perfect, thank you! Would you mind writing that out as the answer so that I can close this question?

Comment: It is actually a duplicate, so I've marked it appropriately ;).